# Mongoose referencing _id not working

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is my code for a login route, I am trying to call `docs._id` but it gives me back `null`. When I call just `docs` it shows this on server side:

`[ { _id: EX unique id,
    username: { user: 'EXUsername', search: 'exusername' },
    pass: 'EXpassword',
    email: 'EXemail' } ]`

I am really confused on why I can't call `docs.pass` or `docs._id` at all but `docs` itself has stuff in it and I can call docs and it gives data back.

my code in node.js:

```
router.post('/loginUser', function(req, res){
  CheckingLogin(req.db, req.body.username, req.body.password, function(bool, docs){
    if(bool && exists(docs)){
    var err = false;
    var handleError = function(e){
    if(err){
      err = true;
      var eDoc = {};
      eDoc.errorCode = 1;
      eDoc.error = e;
      console.log(eDoc);
    }
  }
  /////problem here//////////////////////////////////
  var userID = docs._id;
  console.log(docs._id);
  if(userID != null){
    if(!err){
      tokens.db = req.db;
      tokens.refresher.create(userID, function(token){
        console.log('in token refresher ' + docs);
        res.send('1');
      });
    }else{
      console.log('Token err = true');
    }
  }else{
    console.log('Creator token = null');
    res.send('0');
  }
    }else{
        res.send('0');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: doc**s** suggests an array.

Comment: it's an Object.

Comment: I think its an array of Objects. Notice `[` at the beginning, when console logging `docs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey its an array of object so just get it like this **docs[0]._id** it will work for you.